# Entity Framework datatype length

Tags: entity-framework, c#-4.0

Is there a way to get the datatype length from an entity framework table?

I am needing to create a table in the database if the EF and DB are not in sync, so grab the info from EF to create a script to create the table.

Comment: Entity Framework has Database migrations, maybe you should look into that.

Comment: in entityframework database has no desription for your field. directly provoide varcar to string bigint to Long.

Answer (score 1):

EF is DB agnostic. You can call the underlying DB directly to ask about the Metadata.  You can also for types that allow (decimal, string etc) specify the length you would like in code first scenarios.  EF first does a comparison to check code and DB match.  You can request/trigger migration.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can't because EF maps all the DB fields to primitive data types (C#). So the best solution for this is to think logically for each data types. e.g map string datatype to nvarchar[max], true/false to bit or int....etc etc